# Los datos no se cargan a la tabla de la BD

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Estoy desarrollando un script en PHP para mostrar información de acuerdos y luego guardar esa información en una tabla de la base de datos, pero el problema es que la información no se guarda en la tabla de la base de datos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
include 'conexion.php';
$url = "https://www.pjeveracruz.gob.mx/pjev/viewListasJuzgados";

$data=array('distrito'=>'', 'juzgado'=>'','textTipoAcuerdo'=>'','tipoAcuerdo'=>'','numero'=>'','anio'=>'','fecha'=>'2022-03-01','tipo'=>1);
$curl = curl_init($url);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
/*curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);*/

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
    
if(isset($_POST['textTipoAcuerdo'], $_POST['tipoAcuerdo'],$_POST['numero'])){
    $textTipoAcuerdo=$_POST['textTipoAcuerdo'];
    $tipoAcuerdo=$_POST['tipoAcuerdo'];
    $numero=$_POST['numero'];
    $consulta="insert into acuerdo_edo_veracruz values('".$textTipoAcuerdo."','".$tipoAcuerdo."','".$numero."')";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

Cuando hago `var_dump` de la variable `$consulta`, solo me devuelve `""`.

Y el código para hacer la conexión con la BD es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'acuerdos';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$conexion =new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if($conexion->connect_errno){
    echo "Lo sentimos el sitio web está experimentando problemas";
}
?>
```

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta el  error te devuelve, por favor.

Comment: Ahora quedó editada la pregunta

Comment: Hola! Por favor revisa qué hay en los logs de PHP relacionado con la ejecución de tu script. No sabemos cómo está definida la tabla `acuerdo_edo_veracruz`, así que ntampoco podemos saber si es un problema de tipos de dato. Lo último y más grave: como está tu consulta, es vulnerable a ataques de SQL injection. Revisa cómo usar consultas preparadas

Comment: No tiene ningun sentido lo que estas haciendo. Por un lado descargas un HTML, con la respuesta a tu petición, mediante cURL que almacenas en la variable `$resp`, que **después no usas para nada**, e intentas usar unos $_POST raros que nadie sabe de donde vienen (¿de un formulario quizás?)... Revisa bien el `var_dump` que haces para ver la tabla HTML que te devuelve con bastantes registros, pues si pretendes almacenar eso mejor que primero la despieces mejor y luego con un bucle la pongas en la base de datos.